# How to add parameters to inline callback using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, callback

> The question may be a duplicate but I couldn't find a right & simple answer matching to the current Swift version so I decided to ask the question "again".

- [Swift: Asynchronous callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055313/swift-asynchronous-callback)
- [Passing optional callback into Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466907/passing-optional-callback-into-swift-function)

---

```
func mainFunction() {
   myFunction(Callback: {
        print("") // should be "send this message"
    })
}

func myFunction(Callback: @escaping () -> String) {
  // do something
  Callback(text: "send this message")
}
```

I'm using the code from above but I'd just get a bunch of errors. How is it possible to send via `Callback(text: "send this message")` the text parameter back to the callback-caller (`myFunction`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Define your function

You should define your function this way

```
func myFunction(callback: @escaping (_ text:String) -> Void) {
    callback("send this message")
}
```

> Remember, the value you want to send back to the caller is the **argument** of the callback function, not the return type!

### Call your function

Now you can call it and receive the "send this message" String, look

```
myFunction(callback: { text in
    print(text) // will print "send this message"
})
```

### Trailing Closure Syntax

Even better when the last parameter of your function is a callback, you can use the Trailing Closure Syntax which makes your code much more easier to read.

```
myFunction { text in
    print(text) // will print "send this message"
}
```